# Mongodb can't export data in ArchLinux

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, database

I install mongodb on my ArchLinux and I want to export the database.
but I can't find the command `'mongoexport'`.
I use `"find / -name 'mongo*'` but not find any info about mongoexport and I can't find the install path of mongodb. How can I export my data in mongodb?

I use `pacman -S mongodb`install mongodb,and the mongodb version is 3.2.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the package **mongodb-tools** using the following command

```
pacman -S mongodb-tools
```

mongoexport utility is part of this package on Arch.

Comment: Thanks,I found it.but where is it installed location?

Comment: Good one, works fine and makes sense as well since the tools could consists of mongoexport, mongodump, etc

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but these tools migrated from pacman to yay repo in 2023 already.